# Stop a function after a certain amount of clicks, Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I would to know how to stop a function when a Button is clicked a certain amount of times in Tkinter. My project is a Quiz Program, and what happens is, when you click the *Start* button, the first Question is printed from a text file, into a TextBox. Then, when you choose your multiple choice answer, and click the *Submit* button, the next randomly selected question replaces the previous question in the Textbox, and that process continues for each click of the *Submit* button.

I would like to know how to start a counter for mouse clicks, and stop the printing of lines in the Textbox, after a certain number of clicks.

So that when the *Start* Button is clicked, the counter will go to 1, and then when the *Submit* button is clicked, the same counter will increase by 1 click per time clicked.

Then, after the *Start* button is clicked 1 time, and the *Submit* is clicked 9  times, and the total amount of clicks will equal 10, the printing of lines will stop.

Here is my attempt at the code:

```
def Maths():
Maths = Tk()
Maths.title("Student Mode")
Maths.geometry("1200x600")
lines = open('AnswersMaths.txt').read().splitlines()
count1 = 1                 #I set this as a counter
def start_random():
    myline =random.choice(lines)
    Question_Ans.insert(END, myline)
    count1 + 1        #When the start button is clicked, the button is added by 1
Question_Ans = Text(Maths, width = 50, height = 20)
Question_Ans.place(x=40, y=100)
Start_Button = Button(Maths, width = 10, text = "Start", command=start_random)
Start_Button.place(x=500, y=110)
var = StringVar(Maths)
var.set(None) 
option = OptionMenu(Maths, var,"A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
option.place(x=500, y=160)
c = open("AnswersMaths.txt", 'r+')

def AnswerCode():
    c.write(var.get() + '\n')
    print var.get()
    myline =random.choice(lines)
    Question_Ans.delete('1.0', END)
    Question_Ans.insert(END, myline)
    count1 + 1          #When the submit button is clicked, the button is also added by 1
    if count1 > 10:     #When the counter is > 10, print 'finish'.
        print 'Finish'


Drop_button = Button(Maths,width = 10, text="Submit", command=AnswerCode)
Drop_button.place(x=500, y=200)
def delete_line():
    with open('AnswersMaths.txt', 'r') as fin:
            data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
    with open('AnswersMaths.txt', 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(data[1:])
line_delbutton = Button(Maths,width = 10, text="Finish", command=delete_line).place(x=500, y=240)            
exit1_button=Button(Maths,width = 5, text="Exit", command=Maths.destroy).place(x=1100, y=550)
Inst_Button1=Button(Maths, text="Instructions", command=subj_Instructions).place(x=10, y=10)
Label_maths = Label(Maths, width = 10, font=("Adobe Gothic Std B",30), text="Maths Quiz").place(x=500, y=10)
```

In my code, I tried setting a Variable *count1* as a counter, so when the *Start* button is clicked, *count1* is added by 1, and when the *Submit* button is clicked, it is also added by 1, until when *count1* < 10, the words *Finsh* are printed. Unfortunately, this does not work.

Hope I am clear, still new to python, so any detail on code would be appreciated. Thanks for any help

Comment: If you use a class, then you can define count1 so it can be used through out the class.  Note that count1+1 does nothing as you don't catch the result. For the code you posted, use a list as lists are mutable. count1=[1].  count1[0] += 1. if count1[0] > 10.

Comment: myline =random.choice(lines) can choose the same line multiple times as the choice is random and chooses from all lines, not just lines that have not been chosen.  Use random.shuffle instead to shuffle "lines" in random order and process the list sequentially.